# Getting started with Markov Chain.

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables, markov-chains

I have just started to study Markov Chains from the last chapter (Page-$130$) of the [book of Seymur Lipchuz](https://math24.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/schaums-probability.pdf).

I haven't understood this particular sentence: "*We now consider a sequence of trials whose outcomes, say, $X_1$,$X_2$, ...*" .

What do those random variables represent, say, in the following matrix?

> A Markov Chain $(X_n)_n$ has the following transition matrix:
>   $$P = \begin{bmatrix}
>  0.1 & 0.3 & 0.6\\
>  0 & 0.4 & 0.6\\
>  0.3&0.2&0.5
>  \end{bmatrix}$$
>   with initial distribution $\alpha = (0.2, 0.3, 0.5)$.

What do the terms $X_n$ mean in this context?

What does the term, say, $P(X_9 = 2|X_1 = 2, X_5 = 1, X_7 = 3)$  mean in this context?

what does the term $EX_2$ mean in this context?

Comment: As it says on page 130, "We now consider a sequence of trials whose outcomes, say, X1,X2, ". The $P$ expression is a conditional probability. I don't see $EX_2$ anywhere on that page but I would guess it means the expected value of $X_2$.

Comment: I recommend you read the examples immediately following the definitions. It may be a good idea to use multiple sources if you are learning this on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_i$ is the result of the $i$th "trial" in a sequence. The Markov Chain has three states and the transition matrix $P$ gives the probabilities of moving between states for any particular step in the chain (from state row# to state column#). Note that the row sums of $P$ all equal $1$.

For example, if the state at time $n$ is $1$, the probabilities for the state at time $n+1$ are given by the first row. The probability of state $n+1$ equalling one, given that the state $n$ was one, equals 0.1. This is written $P(X_{n+1} = 1|X_n=1) = 0.1$. The rest of the row gives the other possibilities for transition **from** state one: P(state $1 \rightarrow$ state $2$) $= 0.3$, P(state $1 \rightarrow$ state $3$) $=0.6$.

Lipchuz's point (ii) is important: The outcome of any trial depends at most upon the outcome of the immediately preceding trial.

This means that the conditional probability:
$$(_9=2|_1=2,_5=1,_7=3)$$
is supplying unnecessary information. It might be translated to:
What is the probability of moving from "state 3" to "state 2" in exactly $9-7=2$ steps.